# it { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships) } fails while testing but ok in the sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.2

There is a test for User model

```
it { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships) }
```

fails:

> Failures:
>
> 1) User
>        ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mit { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships)  }←[0m
>        ←[31mNoMethodError:←[0m
>          ←[31mundefined method `it' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0x32 6c310>←[0m ←[36m     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:36:in`block (2 levels) in '←[0m
>
> Finished in 23 seconds ←[31m131 examples, 1 failure←[0m
>
> Failed examples:
>
> ←[31mrspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:35←[0m ←[36m# User ←[0m

At the same time, in rails console --sandbox it looks quite ok:

> irb(main):014:0> user.respond_to?(:reverse_relationships)
>   => true

How can it be?

Comment: It's not related to your question, but if you want to get rid of the `←[` characters in the log, you can set `config.colorize_logging = false` in your `development.rb`(or other environment file)

Comment: Thank you Baldrick! I already I got rid of them by switching to Linux from Windows, but anyone who is still on Windows will appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the error is that the method "it" is undefined in the current context.

It is because you are missing a right brace on line 22 and have two right braces at line 24.

Comment: No. I can't post it, it's too big. I upload it it here http://konakov.biz/files/user_spec.rb

Please take note, that all the others "it" work ok:

subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) } 
  it { should respond_to(:microposts) }
  it { should respond_to(:feed) }
  it { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships) }

Comment: Yes! You're right and I'm blind:

`it { should respond_to(:followed_users)  
it { should respond_to(:reverse_relationships) }    
it { should respond_to(:followers) }}`  

Thanks!

Comment: Good that you found the error, would appreciate if you mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: the bug does not appear on line 34, and there are in fact two bugs that need fixed: they appear on lines **22** and **24**, see my answer as you will need to fix both of them for this to work

Comment: That's right steve, my counting is missing some offset values :)

Comment: Thank you, stephenmurdoch, too!

Comment: Oh, my bad! I deleted comments from the head of the file, thus making initial information not correct. Indeed, in the uploaded file there are 2 bugs on lines 22 and 24.